# In R how do I read a CSV file line by line and have the contents recognised as the correct data type?

Tags: r, csv

I want to read in a CSV file whose first line is the variable names and subsequent lines are the contents of those variables. Some of the variables are numeric and some of them are text and some are even empty.

```
file = "path/file.csv"
f = file(file,'r')
varnames = strsplit(readLines(f,1),",")[[1]]
data = strsplit(readLines(f,1),",")[[1]]
```

Now that data contains all the variables, how do I make it so that data can recognise the data type being read in just like if I did `read.csv`.

I need to read the data line by line (or *n* lines at a time) as the whole dataset is too big to be read into R.

Comment: I'm unclear on why `read.csv('file.csv')` isn't working for you?

Comment: Say I am reading in a 100G file. I want to read 500MB at a time, do some processing and then read the next 500MB. I just can't fit 100G in memory.

Comment: The read.* family of functions allows you to read only so many lines and to skip blocks as well, so you ought to use those parameters rather than attempting to parse lines.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @xiaodai below, that what's really needed here hasn't yet been addressed because the proposed functions are super slow: to read one line at a time in a file with N lines will take $O(N^2)$ time. If one is willing to write some low-level code, and if R has random-access files, it should be possible to get it down to $O(N)$ simply by not losing the random-access position in between calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`chunked`](https://github.com/edwindj/chunked)  or [`disk.frame`](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame) if you don't mind a little tinkering to write out your data.

Both have options to let you read a data chunk-by-chunk

Answer (score 11):

Based on DWin's comment, you can try something like this:

```
read.clump <- function(file, lines, clump){
    if(clump > 1){
        header <- read.csv(file, nrows=1, header=FALSE)
        p = read.csv(file, skip = lines*(clump-1), 
       #p = read.csv(file, skip = (lines*(clump-1))+1 if not a textConnection           
            nrows = lines, header=FALSE)

        names(p) = header
    } else {
        p = read.csv(file, skip = lines*(clump-1), nrows = lines)
    }
    return(p)
}
```

You should probably add some error handling/checking to the function, too.

Then with

```
x = "letter1, letter2
a, b
c, d
e, f
g, h
i, j
k, l"


>read.clump(textConnection(x), lines = 2, clump = 1)
  letter1 letter2
1       a       b
2       c       d

> read.clump(textConnection(x), lines = 2, clump = 2)
  letter1  letter2
1       e        f
2       g        h

> read.clump(textConnection(x), lines = 3, clump = 1)
  letter1 letter2
1       a       b
2       c       d
3       e       f


> read.clump(textConnection(x), lines = 3, clump = 2)
  letter1  letter2
1       g        h
2       i        j
3       k        l
```

Now you just have to *apply over clumps

Comment: I think there is a small error in there: if you do not pass a textConnection (or another connection) but a filename, you need to skip one more line in the first `p = read.csv`, because then the file is reopened after reading the header line.

Comment: I think this solution is good. But have you thought about the implications of using skip = ? To skip to the 1 millionth and 1st record, say, in the background R is reading through the first 1 millionth record! So essentially it's really slow even though it doesn't much memory. Is there a way to read 1 million record, say, then stop, perform some actions on the read data, discard the data from memory then read the next 1 million records without having to read through the previous million (or more) first!!

Answer (score 6):

An alternate strategy that has been discussed here before to deal with very big (say, > 1e7ish cells) CSV files is:

1. Read the CSV file into an SQLite database.
2. Import the data from the database with `read.csv.sql` from the `sqldf` package.

The main advantages of this are that it is usually quicker and you can easily filter the contents to only include the columns or rows that you need.

See [how to import CSV into sqlite using RSqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332976/how-to-import-csv-into-sqlite-using-rsqlite) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun (I'm waiting on a long running computation here :-) ), a version that allows you to use any of the `read.*` kind of functions, and that holds a solution to a tiny error in \Greg's code:

```
read.clump <- function(file, lines, clump, readFunc=read.csv,
    skip=(lines*(clump-1))+ifelse((header) & (clump>1) & (!inherits(file, "connection")),1,0),
    nrows=lines,header=TRUE,...){
    if(clump > 1){
            colnms<-NULL
            if(header)
            {
                colnms<-unlist(readFunc(file, nrows=1, header=FALSE))
                print(colnms)
            }
      p = readFunc(file, skip = skip,
          nrows = nrows, header=FALSE,...)
            if(! is.null(colnms))
            {
        colnames(p) = colnms
            }
    } else {
        p = readFunc(file, skip = skip, nrows = nrows, header=header)
    }
    return(p)
}
```

Now you can pass the relevant function as parameter readFunc, and pass extra parameters too. Meta programming is fun.

Answer (score 3):

On a sidenote : If you really have that huge data, there are (next to the SQLite solution) different packages that will help you handle that without having to resort to tricks as described in these answers.

There's the `ff` and the `bigmemory` package with friends `biganalytics`, `bigtabulate` 'biglm' and so on. For an overview, see eg.

- [Best practices for storing and using data frames too large for memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875795/best-practices-for-storing-and-using-data-frames-too-large-for-memory)
- For an example about plotting : [Plotting of very large data sets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341052/plotting-of-very-large-data-sets-in-r)
- http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html : See under large memory and out-of-memory data

Answer (score 2):

I would try the [LaF package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LaF/index.html):

> Methods for fast access to large ASCII files... It is assumed that
>   the files are too large to fit into memory... Methods are provided
>   to access and process files blockwise. Furthermore, an opened file can
>   be accessed as one would an ordinary data.frame...

I was able to get it seemingly working with the sample code below and it seemed to have the performance you'd expect from a streaming implementation. However, I would recommend you run your own time tests too.

```
library('LaF')

model <- detect_dm_csv('data.csv', header = TRUE, nrows = 600)  # read only 600 rows for type detection

mylaf <- laf_open(model)

print(mylaf[1000])  # print 1000th row
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using `disk.frame`'s `csv_to_disk.frame` and setting `in_chunk_size` would be awesome for this use-case. E.g

```r
library(disk.frame)
csv_to_disk.frame("/path/to/file.csv", in_chunk_size = 1e7)
```