# Reading a csv file that is 53,000 MB large

Tags: r, csv, fread, read.csv

The data is called: data.csv

I tried read.csv('data.csv') and an error message popped up saying the file was too large.

I'm not really sure how to use fread in this situation because when I tried:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- fread("data.csv")
```

That didn't work.

Any ideas?

I ended up trying to install the "bigmemory" package but it says

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘bigmemory’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0)
```

Comment: file is empty means you didn't put in the correct path. Use `list.files` to make sure the file is in the directory you claim.

Comment: A useful tutorial on the `ff` and `bigmemory` packages:  http://www.bytemining.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/r_hpc_II.pdf   Should get you off and running.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it says I need the latest R version 3.2.0: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘bigmemory’ is not available (for R version 3.2.0) Do you know how to update it to that?

Comment: Nick,  if you don't know how to update `R`, how did you install it in the first place?   Sounds like you should read the manuals available for download at CRAN.

Comment: I actually figured that part out. And I have version 3.2.0 but it won't open in that. The only one that is higher than that 3.2.2, but this package has been out for awhile. The main thing I am trying to look for is the structure in the code for me to read the csv file. @CarlWitthoft

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you also try the following code:

```
tab5rows <- read.table("datatable.txt", header = TRUE, nrows = 5)
classes <- sapply(tab5rows, class)
tabAll <- read.table("datatable.txt", header = TRUE, colClasses = classes)
```

Discussed in detail [here](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/%7Erpeng/docs/R-large-tables.html) can significantly improve the speed of reading big files. More importantly, first line would enable you to *look* inside the file. If you can open it the scope for manoeuvre is large. Alternatively, it can be worthwhile to read file in binary:

```
messy_file <- readLines(file("ProblematicData.csv", "rb"), encoding="UTF-8", skipNul=TRUE)
```

---

### Edit

In addition, I would suggest that you have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r) where some options for reading big files are discussed in detail.

My approach to the problem would be:

1. Try first option with `read.table`, alternatively
2. Try `fread` from the `data.table`, alternatively
3. Read as binary

Comment: my data is not a txt file though, it is a csv, so it doesn't read the file datatable.txt @Konrad

Comment: I think you want  "peEk,"  not "peAk"  :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft do you know how to use the code above with a csv file? He uses txt files but I don't have that

Comment: Nick,  a "csv" file **is** a   text file, with a comma defined as the data delimiter.  Don't be fooled by those dang windows file extensions.

Comment: @Nick, the problem of reading `CSV` file via `readLines` was discussed on SO on a couple of occasions, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119667/in-r-how-do-i-read-a-csv-file-line-by-line-and-have-the-contents-recognised-as-t).