# giant csv -> lots of csvs in R

Tags: r, csv, split, subset, file-management

I have a big csv with 116+ million observations. I need to break this down into lots of small CSV's so that I can run it through a different program that has a restrictive file size limit. Is there a way where

```
read df <- bigfile.csv
```

split df into 30 by rows, keeping headers
write out all 30 csvs as littlefile_1.csv; littlefile_2.csv etc.

I know this is pretty rudimentary, but I am pretty new to R.

Comment: Start with `?read.csv` as you can skip rows and limit the number of rows read.  Then check `?write.csv` as there is an append option if you writing observations in batches.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion - I shall try it. Is there anyway to just tell it to split by a specific number. Say I want it to divide into 30 batches, is there a command for that?

Comment: I would look at this question as it has several examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119667/in-r-how-do-i-read-a-csv-file-line-by-line-and-have-the-contents-recognised-as-t